# Update UI from swift to show actual status

Tags: swift, user-interface, process, label

I searched for several days and tried a lot of hints and tips here at stackflow. But I don't get the solution.
I have a lengthy complicated process which should show time by time what it is doing.
I use a NSTextField in my View and give the ViewCotroller (vc) to the process function to get access to it. Then within a loop a try to update the label:

```
for files in filestmp {
    ...

        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
            vc.statusLabel.stringValue = "searching ..."
        }
}
```

With this solution the text is shown after the entire progress has finished. But it should be shown immedeately. I also tried to put all code of the process into the closure, but then I got into trouble writing files or anything like that.

So the only statement needed, is to make sure, the text is shown to the user when the statement is executed. (I'm using XCode 7.3.1)

Comment: Are you running `for files in filestmp` in a background thread?

Comment: It does sound like the entire process is being run on the main thread.

Comment: @Adam H.: Sure. I don't have any wish to run it anywhere else. The updating function should be put into this project as an extension. And it should not force the remaining part to be influenced nor recoded.

Comment: @vacawama: No. I didn't care about that. It is a lengthy task which has be to sequentialy executed. No parallel or background tasks. The updating functionality could be put whereever it is needed.

Comment: If you run a lengthy task on the main thread, your UI will block.  The UI doesn't update until you finish.  You should never run anything that takes more than a fraction of a second on the main thread.  The `dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue...` schedules something to run on the main thread, but it will run only you are done.  It only makes sense if your lengthy task is running on a background thread.

Comment: OK, thank you. So I have to completely redesign my program! (I'm started in 1983 wicth C64, so there was no multithread) :-)

Comment: I started in 1982 with an Atari 400, so I know where you're coming from! :-)